# Remove Bootstrap from Meteor app

Tags: meteor

I want to remove Bootstrap entirely from my meteor app because I use Thoughtbot's Neat and Bourbon as a responsive css framework. So I made sure I have no Bootstrap packages installed, but when I start the application and check the CSS, I see Bootstrap styles in the CSS file.

So I assume Bootstrap is enabled and loaded by default by Meteor?
Is it possible to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've removed all the bootstrap packages, meaning you can't see any when you do this

```
meteor list --using
```

That means you don't have any external bootstrap files included in your project. You can have them however from other sources like your own CSS files or anything you have put in yourself.

Meteor doesn't include bootstrap in projects by default.

Comment: Thanks for that, the package "bootstrap" was still there. I didn't install that by myself, maybe a dependency of the bootrap-accounts-ui package I guess